# Check $_POST['id'] is numeric then do this if not do otherwise

Tags: php, post, isnumeric

Hello I seemed to be failing my code:

```
if (!empty($_POST['id'])) { 
    echo "empty";
} else {
    if (is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
    echo "numeric!";
    } else {
    echo "not empty but not numeric how come?";
    }
}
```

My browser url: hxxp://localhost/upload/?id=9

OUTPUT: not numeric

how come?

please help.

Answer (score 2):

should use  `if(is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {`

---

```
if (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) { 
    echo "yes numeric";
} else {
    echo "not numeric";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first:

```
if (!empty($_POST['id'])) { 
    echo "empty";
} else ...
```

You are saying: If the variable is NOT empty, then echo "empty", and then you are checking if the empty variable is numeric or not (The code in the else is checking an empty variable, that's why it says it's not numeric)

Take out the Exclamation, and clarify yourself on using post or get method, as you are trying to get the POST variable when you passed it through GET

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [$_POST Number and Character checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40372642/post-number-and-character-checker)

```
// test.php

// testing with $_POST['id'] from forum with id = 5 and another test where id = new

$id = $_POST['editid'] ;
echo "<br>---".$id."---<br>";

if (empty($id)) { 
echo "<br>1: empty";
} else {
if (!is_numeric($id)) {
echo "<br>2: This is the number 5";
} else {
echo "<br>3: the must be the word new";
}
}

 // test 2 ... ctype_digit


if (empty($id)) { 
echo "<br>4: empty";
} else {
if (!ctype_digit($id)) {
echo "<br>5: This is the number 5";
} else {
echo "<br>6: the must be the word new";
}
}

// test 3 ... 



if (empty($id)) { 
echo "<br>7: empty";
} else {
if (!preg_match('#[^0-9]#',$id)) {
echo "<br>8: This is the number 5";
} else {
echo "<br>9: the must be the word new";
}
}

/**

result from 5


---5---

3: the must be the word new
6: the must be the word new
8: This is the number 5

results from "new"



**/
```

Comment: ---new---

2: This is the number 5
5: This is the number 5
9: the must be the word new

Comment: ---new---

     2: This is the number 5
     5: This is the number 5
     9: the must be the word new

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing parrameter via URL so use

```
if (is_numeric($_GET['id']))
```

Or use

```
if (is_numeric($_REQUEST['id'])) {
```

Or else it will show an undefied variable hence will fallback to each block

Answer (score 0):

Its easy, "id" is in the $_GET array, but you check existance in the $_POST array

```
if (empty($_GET['id'])) { ... }
```

should be correct. And then you can use $_GET['id'] or $_REQUEST['id'].

**Note**: $_REQUEST holds all variables in $_POST and $_GET

The correct code should be:

```
 if (empty($_GET['id'])) { 
     echo "empty";
 } else {
     if (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
         echo "numeric!";
     } else {
         echo "not empty but not numeric how come?";
     }
 }
```

Instead of $_GET you can also use $_REQUEST